# How to change pagination of strava api response

Tags: python, pagination

I am trying to get segments efforts from strava's api using python but each time I make a request for any particular segment, the response is a list of the default setting of 30 number of segments. I haven't had any luck changing the pagination parameters in the header. Any ideas?

Thanks,
minh

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests

token ='xxxx'  #the public token given when you are registered

segments = ['120']  #list of segment id's to be used

header={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'per_page':'100', 'page':'2'}

for segment in segments:
    url ='https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/' + segment +  'all_efforts'
    r=requests.get(url,headers = header )
    jobj= json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `per_page` and `page` should be passed as parameters rather than headers.

```
import json
import requests

token = 'xxxx'  #the public token given when you are registered

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
params = {'per_page':100, 'page':2}

url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/120/all_efforts'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
jobj = json.loads(r.text)
```

Then `len(jobj)` will equal 100.